# What determines the order of something's nationalities?

Tags: adjectives, word-order

I know English has a set '[general opinion, specific opinion, size, shape, age, colour, nationality, material](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/adjectives/order-adjectives)' order for adjectives, but how is the ordering of multiple nationalities decided?

For example, 'British-American' sounds right, whilst 'American-British' sounds daft.

I can see why, for example, 'African-American' is the way it is because it refers to an American of African descent, rather than a joint African and American citizen, but is there a rule for the orderings of people who possess dual nationalities/projects delivered by companies from various countries/etc.?

Or how about more than two nationalities: why is *Rome* a '[British-American-Italian historical drama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rome_(TV_series))' rather than an American-Italian-British one?

Comment: Related: [Why is it “ladies and gentlemen” instead of “gentlemen and ladies”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/321908) and various questions linked to that one

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Finnish Swedes" or "Swedish Finns"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/232777/finnish-swedes-or-swedish-finns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A British American is phonetically easier to say than American British.
Similarly for British American Italian.
If you're referring to a person then a British American is an American of British descent whereas an American Briton would be a Brit of American descent.

Comment: What does “phonetically easier” mean?