# One word for Hindi-speaker

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the correct word for Hindi speaker, is it the Hindu or the Indian?

Comment: I think both of them are not correct. Hindu is one who follows Hindu religion and Indian is one who is from indian subcontinent.

Comment: The correct term for a Hindi speaker is either *Hindi speaker* or *speaker of Hindi*. There is no single word for this concept in English.

Comment: Or you can generally refer to them as non-native speaker.

Comment: As I understand it (and I am not an expert on the subcontinent) *Hindi* is the language of the people of *Hindustan* and nearby areas. *Hindu* has philosophical, religious, social and cultural standing and can also refer to anyone living in India east of the Indus river. But *Hindi* and *Hindu* are not, to my understanding connected semantically.

Comment: @MassKent: Why could a speaker of Hindi not be a native speaker? _Native_ speaker does by no means mean _speaker of English_!

Comment: Apparently you haven’t noticed that *Hindi-speaker* is already one word.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Hindi is not the language of the Hindus, it never was.**

*India is a potpourri of varied sects and religions.*

> [Hindi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindi) (हिन्दी), or more precisely Modern Standard Hindi (मानक
>   हिन्दी), is a standardised and Sanskritised register of the Hindustani
>   language.
>
> [Hindustani](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindustani_language) (Hindustani: हिन्दुस्तानी, ہندوستانی[a][7]),
>   historically also known as Hindavi, Dehlvi, Urdu, and Rekhta, is the
>   lingua franca of **North India and Pakistan**.
>   (wiki)

Currently there are [22 official languages in India](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_language#India). 
A plurality of speakers in India speak Hindi. Indian from every religion - i.e., Muslims, Jews, Christians, Budhhists, Jains etc. speak/can speak in Hindi.

> An Indian court clarified that [Hindi is not the national language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindi) of India because the constitution does not mention it as such. Outside of Asia, Hindi is also an official language in **Fiji**.

**A Hindi speaker from the most populous Northern states is termed "native Hindi-speaker".**

Comment: In india there are hindus who doesn't speak hindi and also hindi speakers who doesnt follow hinduism

Comment: I think he asked for one word. Not one more word. ;)

Answer (score 11):

Someone who speaks Hindi can be a Muslim Irishman or a German Jew.

What language someone speaks (even as a mother tongue!) does not necessarily mean anything about that person's geographical or ethnic background.

An **Indian** is someone from India. They can speak many languages, and Hindi *might* be one. They may identify with Hinduism religiously, culturally or socially, but they may be Muslims or Christian or Buddhist or whatever.

A **Hindu** is someone who identifies religiously, culturally or socially with Hinduism, but they may speak many languages, and Hindi *might* be one. They may be German, English, American or come from or live anywhere else in the world.

A **speaker of Hindi** is someone who speaks the Hindi language. They may identify with Hinduism religiously, culturally or socially, but they may be Muslims or Christian or Buddhist or whatever. They may be German, English, American or come from or live anywhere else in the world.

Comment: Asian Indians speak Hindi; American Indians do not.

Comment: @tchrist, presumably it's not more unlikely for a Native American to speak Hindi than it is for a German Jew to speak it.

Answer (score 3):

Given that someone who speaks French can be called a Francophone, and someone who speaks English can be called an Anglophone, one could use the same standard and refer to speakers of Hindi as Hindiphones.  While this may not be an already-established word in the English lexicon, many words in English were contrived. So, say "Namaste" to the Hindiphones in your life!

Comment: Why not *hindophone* or *hinduphone*? It seems like `o` comes most often before the suffix `-phone` (with this meaning).

Comment: Related: [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37058/root-ophone-construction-to-describe-speakers-of-a-language) thread on -ophone suffix

Answer (score 1):

In the language Hindi, the correct single word for somebody who speaks Hindi would be *hindibhashi* (हिन्दीभाषी), the literal translation of which is "one who speaks Hindi." There is no regional or religious or other identity associated with this than the literal meaning.

There is no single word translation of that in English.

The answer by Mysti Sinha gives great background on the language and many things associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the word you are looking for is - **HINDIPHONE**.
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hindiphone